# Simple login using php, javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

So I'm currently trying to complete a school project, but currently stuck on creating the login using php, javascript, json and ajax. I know how to make a simple login only using php, but I'm quite the novice using javascript and ajax. We are not allowed to use jQuery or mySql, so only using php, javascript, ajax and json. Thanks for the help in advance.

this is my ajax.js file

```
var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener("click", sendRequest, false);
}

function sendRequest(){
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = getRequest;

    var user = input.value['username'];

    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "loggIn.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(user);
}

function getRequest(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);

        if(jsonObj !== 'undefined'){
            window.location.replace('privat.php');
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
```

so I have a few question regarding this, is it valid to use

```
var user = input.value['username'];
```

or is there another way to get the value from what the user puts in the input form "username"?

also, this function:

```
function getRequest(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);

        if(jsonObj !== 'undefined'){
            window.location.replace('privat.php');
        }
    }
}
```

after it gets the response from the loggIn.php file and the user input is correct I want it to redirect to "privat.php" but not quite sure how.

Here is the rest of my code:
privat.php

```
<a href="loggOut.php">Logga ut</a>

<br>
<?php
echo "user:" . $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

loggIn.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];

        echo json_encode($_SESSION['user']);
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>Sessioner</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Logga in" name="login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

loggOut.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

header("Location: loggIn.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var user = input.value['username'];` is definitely invalid. You need to use one of the following:

```
var user = document.forms[0].elements['username'].value;    
var user = document.querySelector('form').elements['username'].value;
var user = document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value;
```

If you haven't learned about CSS selectors yet, I'd say go for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = input.value['username'];
```

The above statement is wrong.

You can get a form element by using:

```
var username = document.forms["loginform"]["username"].value;
```

Give a name to the form and you can get the input string.